# Process Builder printing the output without any sysout, i want to store the output in List<String>

Tags: java, process, inputstreamreader

I want to store the list of folders with name ending with MS present at PROJECT_LOCATION in a List ===>

```java
  ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder().directory(Paths.get(PROJECT_LOCATION)
        .toFile())
        .command("cmd.exe",
             "/c",
             "dir /b *MS;")
        .inheritIO()
        .redirectErrorStream(true);
  Process process = processBuilder.start();
```

this much code is prinitng the names of folders ending with MS, but i want to store the values in a List

I tried =>

```java
        List<String> msList=new ArrayList<>();  
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
            msList.add(line);
        }
        process.waitFor();
        System.out.println("ok!    "+  msList.size());
```

but the list size is printing to be 0. It is not reading the InputStream Lines.
Does it not support for these kind of commands.....?

Console output===>

```
CartMS
CustomerMS
PaymentMS
ProductMS
ok!    0
```

Comment: *this much code is prinitng the names of folders ending with MS, but i want to store the values in a List*. This doesn't really make sense. You're not trying to read stdout twice are you? If so, that obviously won't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you starting an external program to list files when there's a much better alternative?

```
List<String> msList;
try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(Paths.get(PROJECT_LOCATION), 1)) {
    msList = stream.filter(Files::isRegularFile) // also filters out PROJECT_LOCATION itself
            .map(f -> f.getFileName().toString())
            .filter(f -> f.endsWith("MS"))
            .toList(); // for older Java versions: .collect(Collectors.toList())
}
```

Or without streams:

```
List<String> msList = new ArrayList<>();
try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(PROJECT_LOCATION), "*MB")) {
    for (Path file : stream) {
        msList.add(file.getFileName().toString());
    }
}
```